# PHP namespace not finding class in same namespace in same directory - works in dev, not prod

Tags: php, heroku, namespaces, yii2

I have the following PHP files. It works in dev. They have the same namespace, and same PHP version. When I deploy to Heroku, it gives an error. Do you know why?

`Product.php`

```
namespace app\models;
class Product extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
public function getEbay()    {
    return $this->hasOne(Ebay::className(), ['product_id' => 'id'])->inverseOf('product'); # line 56
```

`Ebay.php`

```
namespace app\models;
class Ebay extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
```

> 2015-03-25T02:00:01.003508+00:00 app[web.1]: [25-Mar-2015 02:00:01 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'app\models\Ebay' not found in /app/models/Product.php on line 56

```
>heroku run php --version
Running `php --version` attached to terminal... up, run.5360
PHP 5.6.6 (cli) (built: Feb 19 2015 10:11:22)
Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.4-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2015, by Zend Technologies
```

Local:

```
$ php --version
PHP 5.6.6 (cli) (built: Feb 25 2015 13:54:50)
Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies
```

---

Ok I even put the `use` in the `index.php` and it still fails.

```
C:\Users\Chloe\workspace\project>heroku run cat web/index.php
Running `cat web/index.php` attached to terminal... up, run.3679
<?php

// comment out the following two lines when deployed to production
if ($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] == 'localhost' || $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] == '127.0.0.1') {
  defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG', true);
  defined('YII_ENV') or define('YII_ENV', 'dev');
}

require(__DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php');
require(__DIR__ . '/../vendor/yiisoft/yii2/Yii.php');

$config = require(__DIR__ . '/../config/web.php');

use app\models; Ebay::className();
(new yii\web\Application($config))->run();

C:\Users\Chloe\workspace\project>heroku logs
...
2015-03-26T17:10:13.590855+00:00 app[web.1]: [26-Mar-2015 17:10:13 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Ebay' not found in /app/web/index.php on line 14
```

Comment: This is probably not your issue, but  you haven't put use app\models\Ebay before your products class declaration, I wondered if you'd just not put in in the code here.

Comment: And... where is your autoloader?

Comment: @JoeMiller No, that's not my issue. It works in dev. But even before you commented, I tried to add `use \app\models; use \app\models\Ebay;` and `use app\models; use app\models\Ebay;` after the `namespace` declaration and it still didn't work.

Comment: @dzuelke It's a Yii2 app. The autoloader is in the standard place for Yii2 apps. I don't know. I think it's in `vendor/autoload.php`.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found it. It was because the file was named `EBay.php` in Git and Heroku but `Ebay.php` on the Windows file system. Curse you Git! This solved it.

```
git mv -f models/EBay.php models/Ebay.php
```

This command failed so I had to investigate further:

```
heroku run ls models/Ebay.php
```